# How to encapsulate global variable in PHP extension for each thread?

Tags: php, c, multithreading, pthreads, thread-local-storage

I develop some PHP extension. This extension has to work with pthreads together. I have faced with a problem because global variables, declared globally (in top of C code), they are touchable from each PHP thread. For example we have simple PHP extension code written in C laguage:

```
#include <php.h>

int test_var;

PHP_FUNCTION(set_var) {
  test_var = 123;
}

PHP_FUNCTION(print_var) {
  printf("%d", test_var);
}
```

If we run the following code in first PHP thread:

```
set_var();
```

And then run the following PHP code in the second thread:

```
print_var();
```

The output of second thread will be 123. This means I have to use global C variables very carefully. Because it may be overwritten and my script crashed. As variant I can define variables inside the functions and pass this variables to another functions from functions where variable was defined. But I can't do it in some situations when several functions have to have access to some variable. Can anybody tell me a good practices for this, please ?

Comment: Global variables in any language can be signs of poor design, but sometimes they are just convenient to use (perhaps too much so).  You will be much better off passing the required variables around as parameters.  Problem is that without potentially masses of code it would be difficult to provide a complete solution to your problem other than suggesting how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the global variable thread-local be doing:

```
_Thread_local int test_var; /* for C11 or higher */
```

For other versions of C this might do:

```
thread_local int test_var;
```

or this

```
__thread int test_var;
```

Comment: Still, if using pointers be aware that the data they point to might not be "thread local".